# Mount HW RAID 10 and a specific partition inside the RAID

Tags: centos, mount, raid

I'm trying to mount a RAID 10 (GPT formatted) on Centos 7 and move some data in a specific partition.
Below I'm posting all the approaches I've tested but none worked. What is it that I'm missing? How should I approach what I want to accomplish? 
The RAID sits on a Intel Controller and has Windows Installed in 1 of the 2 partitions and the other one contains data, so I wouldn't like to reformat them.

```
[root@localhost ~]# blkid
/dev/mapper/centos-root: UUID="19e4fc26-7311-4c75-b742-83885e2c71cb" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sde3: UUID="0GpcBI-AY6Z-EdQF-7IjY-emDo-6GLe-XJq0nw" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="44ac6033-1e04-4420-9ae0-48973e54d2db"
/dev/sde2: UUID="413ac650-6040-4c54-be78-d5803f910fcf" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="9c694c74-8133-426d-a201-e800db8725a2"
/dev/sde1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="82C8-E6C7" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="861f6846-492d-4274-9df4-1047a0b1f5c4"
/dev/mapper/centos-swap: UUID="9ac50753-737f-49f4-8fe7-27572dcb9564" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdd: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdc: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
```

*blkid* shows the above result. And below you can see the *fdisk -l*

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x36488a5c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x36488a5c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
```

When I'm trying to mount the /dev/sdb1 device I get the following error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/raid10_1/
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
```

If I try the following, I get the same error

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/raid10_1/
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
```

If I try to mount with ntfs-3g I get a "failed to access volume" error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt/raid10_1/
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What happens when you run fdisk on /dev/sdb?

Comment: fdisk /dev/sdb

The device presents a logical sector size that is smaller than
the physical sector size. Aligning to a physical sector (or optimal
I/O) size boundary is recommended, or performance may be impacted.
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.